# Implicit linebreaks in LaTeX equations

Tags: latex, line-breaks, implicit, equation

I wonder if there is any way to invert the way the LaTeX interprets linebreaks in equations? E.g., I dont want to insert them explicitly like,

```
\begin{gather}
x = y \\
a = c
\end{gather}
```

, but implicitly like,

```
\begin{gather}
x = y
a = c
\end{gather}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is against the intention of TeX’s author, who believed that math must be typeset by hand. I tried `obeylines`, but to no avail. I guess it’s possible by making new line active, but you should ask the cracks over at [Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), a branch of Stack Overflow for TeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

The [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/breqn.html) package will automatically insert linebreaks in equations when the line is full. I don't know of anything that will do break as you ask. If it is a big deal you could use perltex to define a macro that would do it for you. I will try to mock one up as an example.

Comment: Having a bit of problems with my perltex solution, turns out it is hard to capture macro input with linebreaks correctly